# Run Hybris unit test in intellij Idea community edition

Tags: intellij-idea, sap-commerce-cloud

i want to run hybris unit test using intellij community edition like how we do it on eclipse.
I don't want to use Hybris intergation plugin as it was failed to defect the unittest that are present in custom directory. when i try to run the test Intellij native build is triggering but not the ant build. and i am resolving the dependencies whenever intellij throws me build fail with those errors.
Can anyone help me to set this up or guide me through what all necessary steps to follow.
I am using latest version of community edition , Junit - 4 & Mockito for writing unit tests.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to Run the tests once i resolved all the errors that was throwing by intellij.

refer the [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZYHg.png)

Once you click on that run button, you get build errors, once you resolve those build errors then automatically that test will run. if it says shorten the command line then

Please refer this article by [Intellij](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/10/intellij-idea-2017-3-eap-configurable-command-line-shortener-and-more/), hope this helps.